# auto call react this.function() in a onClick JSX event without getting an error

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that I want to run which plays a particular audio file when the screen loads and when the onClick is clicked by the user.

```
playSound = () => {
    let audioSound = new Audio(this.state.activity[this.state.index].audio0);
    return audioSound.play();
}
```

I want it to run onload, so I included the parentheses in front of the onClick function call.

```
onClick={this.playSound()}
```

The only problem with this is that I get this error in the console when it loads or I click on the onClick again.

```
Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type
```

I'd like to know why this specific error is popping up.

I'm able to get the audio working by calling the this.playSound() inside of my render(), but I feel like there's a cleaner way that I don't know about.

Comment: Just replace onClick={this.playSound()} with onClick={this.playSound}

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `onClick` with following

```
onClick={this.playSound}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the `playSound` function any time the element is clicked, you have to change it to `onClick={this.playSound}` as other people have suggested.

It sounds like you **also** want `playSound` to run when the component loads for the first time? If so, add `this.playSound()` inside the lifecycle method `componentDidMount`. This would mean your component has to be a class-based stateful component, not a functional stateless component. You mentioned a `render` method in your question, which makes me believe your component is already class-based. Here is how this lifecycle method would look like for you:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.playSound();
}
```

If you want `playSound` to run every time any state or props change in your component (which seems unlikely), you could put `this.playSound()` at the beginning of your `render` method.

Hope this helps!